# Property 'title' does not exist on type, Argument of type?

Tags: typescript

я написал код который из сервера может получить 2 типа [массива](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/FAehEZmAbBTAXABAD0QXkQbWI3uDeOexARPAJbxwkBciJA8gHayIAKArkwMYAWiAWQCGTRAGUhlIQFshiBgAcFkxABVxvcgCckAKSHKWAZ1YBBJuWmthTAOZyBsJkcQBhaAHt4muyQA0RMS4JApa5NywtPQAJODgAHQArACc-oFBIVoeACZi8ELwkXQkLADuaUF4JEaaSuS+xeQuAGZasJEBlcFGHtDZUSQAzBVd1VrcA7JMIGwAVgBM8wCaAEocyQCeI5UkQtDwA8ysnDz8NuKS+bLySirqYpo6iPqGsCaI5pbWIvaCTi7uLw+WzbDLkfrFOaLVbrLadUbwDwDKHLNabEjpAC+8II6VIFCoRXojiYAHIXAA5ACiAHVxBwFLAtFNEABxDbScT1WxweAueAAWhq2iQACEchsAEYcch9bmIABilGMLjECg8OgBnm8b1BpFC4SJJFiABY9VVQjk8gUjWVzd1agpuQNomacRken0BoMAAz2+hGcaTEQgeYMcAKIzZaTzZJuvFVPYHYok8mIal0sQMpks9mcsTc3n8oWPMUS6Wy7LypXwFXidWatza3i692kcEDMMRqMxuP+shI4pdyPR2NmrFQAC6iDA8A2jMQ0g4RiQktYzSEETYWWyHG48AAMk14JhJ1AwPMoLzEBt0FhkH4H8hp7P56wlyvEGvEButzu94ex6nqeQA) но я получаю ошибку 23.25 lines I get two Errors The 'title' property does not exist for the type and the type argument,Я ожидаю, что строки 23 типа faceProductList [] и 25 типа faceProductList [] [] [код](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAnkgClA9gEwK4JgAywAzmMgN4BQyyUEcOWIANgJ7JjBisQBcyclFABzANy16jZm04AHEUkHCxkugyYsOyRbgDKYOJBVgRICVM2ydpABbB58safOWNM7Z1JZWOV2pWnnJCUAgBFurSWiHA-kJmgR4xOmBYEZYAvtTUCKxwpKTI+tAAbtBUUnSKwKXGKHhQrBnIALzIAOR2YGDypPwA9AMwWFgADGMATJMAdDDADABGBRDAWDMIWAC2Ax1R1XiLrMAIyAXsIKcMAI54EOQAFHEZAJSCmNtkEAA8D2gQH3whBI5AA2gBdZAAH1QiAB2CBxDIYBeEIAfJU6FisZsQORpEV2nAAO5wHioCBgBB2B4AAwAJJQwA5SDNGqxMoy4plaS99tjkLj8QxSABBKBQQR-OGAghIsGQmH-WXA5GoyFtM6k8kimYAKx8IAefKqAoYYEaIAJ4qg-Oy2Pkh2Op3Ol2QdjgIBwfCgT3iqgsABpkHVWHcSnAwnZXlRkKbsSSyRRmWQZjc7o84i941iZsyIEaHpGoHB2C82hjKHGBTXkMAYH6XlWc7XpBaoFazhLS3NgKxIL6HkyeHxMuXWhjuLwIDNQHk8Dh7g9Q+HGFGXtnW9jMhBWKQIDQt7XzZbkBCNiwEMYHjNb8XS5uj8h7UeWwKx6bspkgA)

```
interface faceProductList {
  readonly title: string;
  readonly price: string;
  readonly prodState: string;
  readonly shipping: string;
  readonly sold: string;
  readonly src: string;
  readonly id: string;
  readonly to: string;
}

class Server {
    private url: string = 'https://foo0022.firebaseio.com/';
    public async request(id: string): Promise<(faceProductList[] | faceProductList)[]> {
        const res = await fetch(`${this.url}${id}`);
        const resArr: (faceProductList[] | faceProductList)[]  = await res.json();
        return resArr;
    }
    public async handler(id: string, valueSearch: string) { 
        await this.request(id)
        .then((array) => { 
            if(id){ 
              return  array.filter(({title}) => title.includes(valueSearch))
            }else{
                return [].concat(...array)
            }

            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это потому что Вы написали 2 взаимоисключающих условия:
либо `faceProductList[]`  либо `faceProductList[][]`. Приходит либо масив либо массив массивов, во втором случае нет `title` и поэтому компилятор ругается. 
Оператор `|` не будет работь для разных типов интферфесов и их комбинаций, типа `масив сущностей` или сама `сущность`.